# If statement using date

Tags: php, if-statement

Right now im using this if statement, but i need to modify it so that it shows include if they signed up AFTER today's date, instead of being equal to

```
    <?php
    if ($userinfo['signed_up']=="2011-08-29 09:00:00")
      include("launchbuilder_gorilla.php");
    else
      include("launchbuilder.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: is `$userinfo['signed_up']` stored as a string?

Comment: use `date()` function instead of this date and `strtotime()` for comparing numbers.

Comment: By "after today's date", do you mean "after Aug 29th 2011" (hardcoded), or "whatever today's date is on that date"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($userinfo['signed_up'] > "2011-08-29 09:00:00")
```

Should work, according to PHP's in-built type-casting, and that date format. If you need to transfer the current time to that format, use:

```
if ($userinfo['signed_up'] > date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
```

However, as deceze pointed out, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense, so you might want something like:

```
if ($userinfo['signed_up'] >= date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"))
```

To check if they signed up at any point 'today'. See [the `date()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtotime($userinfo['signed_up']) > time())
```

Back to the Future?

Comment: Maybe the OP uses a year 9999 future signup date for a test account and needs to include different code. It's not unheard of to have bogus values for test accounts (user id -1 etc).

Answer (score 0):

can go the object-based approach: using [date_diff()](http://il.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)